# Hibernate update table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate and following the tutorial at http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html, I have a question about the main class in that tutorial.

I understand that

```
Set phoneNumbers = new HashSet();
phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("house","32354353"));
phoneNumbers.add(new Phone("mobile","9889343423")); 
Student student = new Student("Eswar", phoneNumbers);
session.save(student);
transaction.commit();
```

insert new records into three tables. But if this student gets another number

```
Phone work = new Phone("mobile","12345678");
```

How could I update the PHONE and STUDENT_PHONE tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of things. This code will work:

```
Set phoneNumbers = new HashSet();
student.setPhoneNumbers(phoneNumbers); // Add the phone numbers to the Student

Phone phone = new Phone("house","32354353");
session.save(phone); // Persist the new object
phoneNumbers.add(phone);

Phone phone = new Phone("mobile","9889343423");
session.save(phone); // Persist the new object
phoneNumbers.add(phone);

Student student = new Student("Eswar", phoneNumbers);
session.save(student);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Probably I did not explain my question well. I can get the code working. What I want to know is after running the main class in the tutorial, there is a student with name "Eswar" in the  STUDENT table. But later we want to update Eswar's details by adding in his working phone number, what should I do with it. I have tried using session.save(student), but i get two "Eswar" entries in the STUDENT table.